# Add timestamp to oh-my-zsh robbyrussell theme

Tags: zsh, themes

I want to add a timestamp to my command prompt in oh-my-zsh. This is the current theme prompt ([robbyrussell](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme)):

```
local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ %s)"
PROMPT='${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="git:(%{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}✗%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%})"
```

Any idea how can add the timestamp?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to the zshmisc man page there are several `%` codes for date and time, eg:

```
 %D     The date in yy-mm-dd format.
 %T     Current time of day, in 24-hour format.
 %t %@  Current time of day, in 12-hour, am/pm format.
 %*     Current time of day in 24-hour format, with seconds.
 %w     The date in day-dd format.
 %W     The date in mm/dd/yy format.
 %D{strftime-format}
```

The last one allows codes listed in the strftime(3) [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).
Edit your `~/.zshrc` file and add at the end a new PROMPT value, eg:

```
 PROMPT='${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} %D %T % %{$reset_color%}'
```

Comment: This doesn't stay after I close the terminal window.  I have to do source ~/.zsh every time how do I avoid that?

Comment: There was a typing mistake in my answer. The file to use is `~/.zshrc` not `~/.zsh`.

Answer (score 55):

If you want add date/time to the right, you set RPROMPT

```
local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT='${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
RPROMPT="[%D{%y/%m/%f}|%@]"
```

[image]

Comment: its definitely goes better on the right side since I already have a lot of stuff on the left prompt

Comment: in my case `nano ~/.zshrc` and added `RPROMPT="%{$fg[yellow]%}[%D{%f/%m/%y}|%@]"` as last line to set right prompt with yellow color

Comment: @VictorR.Oliveira you would want to add `%{$reset_color%}` at the end to avoid having the yellow messing up the rest of the lines.

Comment: +1 for `RPROMPT`

Comment: Is it possible to set the time zone to something else with this?

Answer (score 11):

I added this `%D{%m/%f/%y}|%D{%L:%M:%S}` to the main theme to display the date and time as `mm/dd/yy | hh:mm:ss`.

So here is the full command I use:

```
PROMPT='%D{%m/%f/%y}|%D{%L:%M:%S} ${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}${NEWLINE}$ '
```

Which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To get full datetime and zone

[Sun 11 Aug 2019 20:41:53 AEST]

I place

RPROMPT="%{$fg[green]%}[%D{%c}]"

in my ~/.zshrc file

Answer (score 3):

Add the following at the end of your `.zshrc` to get a similar output as shown in the GIF.

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜% %{$fg_bold[blue]%} [%D{%L:%M:%S}]% ${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}'
TMOUT=1
TRAPALRM() {
    zle reset-prompt
}
```

GIF: [live-time-oh-my-zsh.gif](https://i.ibb.co/2dYKvYC/live-time-oh-my-zsh.gif)

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me

```
%D{%b %d, %Y - %T}
```

Format: Aug 10, 2020 - 22:26:54

Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html